# Windows can't fix blurry apps

Tags: windows-10, resolution

I have a laptop with a 1920x1080px 14" Monitor, where a bigger screen with the same resolution is connected to (I don't know the size of it, I guess it's about 20"-21").

The Windows feature "Fix apps that are blurry" is on, but on the bigger screen, things like Visual Studio or Outlook still appear blurry. That's not the case for all Apps, but these two are the ones I recognized it with. For example, Excel doesn't have that problem.

Also my laptop screen makes apps appear at 150% size, but all apps are looking sharp there, no matter how big they are displayed.

Comment: Is the large screen set to its native resolution?

Comment: Yes, windows recommended 1920x1080, so I didn't change that, while it suggested the 150% for the laptop screen, so I did that one

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of a blurry window and screen model? (you can [edit] the question)

Comment: Well, at the moment it somehow managed to fix it. I'll do it if the error reoccurs

Comment: This is almost always a graphics driver issue if ClearType is turned on and configured in Windows... have you tried updating your graphics driver to the most recent available?  The 150% size is due to DPI, which can be changed in Settings > System > Display

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem but i was able to fix it with the specific programs settings that had this issue particularly.

Note down which specific programs have the problem.
Right-click on the program icon (not the shortcut) and choose properties.
Click the "Compatibility" tab.
Check the box labeled "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings".
Restart the program